# Add One to Many relationship in junction table in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, foreign-key-relationship, junction-table

I have two table with Many to Many relationship

```
Table 1           Table 2          Junction Table
---Game---      ---Player---      ---GamePlayer---
gameID(PK)      playerID(PK)      gameID
gameDetails     playerDetails     playerID 
                                  PK(gameID,playerID)
```

I have one more table "Setting"

```
Table 
---Setting---
settingID
settingName
settingValue
FK(gameID,PlayerID)
```

which have relation with Game and Player in way that

- A player can have number of settings for each game.

I dont know how to implement this in hibernate.

Apologies if this is a simple fix. I am new to the hibernate. Some help or better solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For setting you can define entity as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Setting{
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    private Game game;
    @ManyToOne
    private Player player;
    ...
}
```

and if you want to have a list of settings of a player you can define in `Player` object:

```
@Entity
public class Setting{
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="player")
    private List<Setting> settings;
}
```